# How to create and move multiple shapes in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a space type game for a school competition. Im going to use stars (white dots) moving outwards to give an effect of moving in space. Next I would check to see if a star's x cords are less than the centre or the screen (move the star to the left) and if the x coordinate is larger (Move to the right).  However, I can't seem to make more than one instance of the stars class.[Here is an image of the kind of thing I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAJrh.png) . Help is very appreciated.

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
caption = pygame.display.set_caption("sapce game")
screen.fill((56, 56, 56))
white = (255, 255, 255)

class Stars:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 600)
        self.y = random.randint(0, 400)
        self.pos = (self.x, self.y)

    def move(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (self.x, self.y), 4)
        self.y -= 1
        self.x -= 2
        screen.fill((56, 56, 56))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (self.x, self.y), 4)
        pygame.display.update()


s = Stars()

run = True
while run:
    s.move()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to put `scrre.fill` and  `pygame.display.update()` in the main application loop. Remove this calls from `Stars.move`:

```py
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            quit()

    screen.fill((56, 56, 56))
    s.move()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, you want to clear the display once, then draw all the stars and finally update the display.

Create a list of stars:

```py
star_list = []
for i in range(10):
    star_list.append(Stars())
```

Move and draw the stars in a loop:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    screen.fill((56, 56, 56))
    for s in star_list:
        s.move()
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Example code:

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
caption = pygame.display.set_caption("sapce game")
screen.fill((56, 56, 56))
white = (255, 255, 255)

class Stars:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, 600)
        self.y = random.randint(0, 400)
        self.dx, self.dy = 0, 0
        while self.dx == 0:
            self.dx = random.randint(-2, 2)
        while self.dy == 0:
            self.dy = random.randint(-2, 2)
        self.pos = (self.x, self.y)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
        if self.x <= 0 or self.x >= 1200:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.y <= 0 or self.y >= 800:
            self.dy = -self.dy
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (self.x, self.y), 4)

star_list = []
for i in range(10):
    star_list.append(Stars())

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            quit()

    screen.fill((56, 56, 56))
    for s in star_list:
        s.move()
    pygame.display.update()
```